# How to access more than 10 item's detail in Amazon api using php?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, api

I am working with amazon api and have used code from online sources http://www.codediesel.com/php/accessing-amazon-product-advertising-api-in-php/.

I would like to get more than 10 product's detail when I make a search query using amazon api. I am aware about the amazon api policy of getting 10 data per call but is it possible to get more data by creating loop or something?

When I make a request I have assigned following parameteres

```
 $parameters = array("Operation"     => "ItemSearch",
                     "SearchIndex"   => "Electronics",
                     "ResponseGroup" => "Images,ItemAttributes,EditorialReview,Offers ",  
                     "ItemPage"=>"10",
                     "Keywords" => $search                                                                                                                                              );
```

So even though I have asked for 10 pages of result, I am unsure of how to display data from every page (1 to 10 ) so in total I get 100 items when I make a query. I get following response when I try to make run the code:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
    [Request] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
        [IsValid] => True            
        [ItemSearchRequest] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
            [ItemPage] => 10 
            [Keywords] => laptop 
            [ResponseGroup] => Array ( 
                [0] => Images 
                [1] => ItemAttributes 
                [2] => EditorialReview 
                [3] => Offers 
            ) 
            [SearchIndex] => Electronics 
        ) 
    ) 
    [TotalResults] => 3383691 
    [TotalPages] => 338370 
    [MoreSearchResultsUrl] => http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/redirect.html?camp=2025&creative=12734&location=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.co.uk%2Fgp%2Fsearch%3Fkeywords%3Dlaptop%26url%3Dsearch-.................(and on)
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you would need to loop through 10 times and appends an array or object.  The AWS documentation says that `ItemPage` is actually the page of results, so you would just need to page through it 10 times to get your 100 results.

AWS Documentation on `ItemPage`:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/PagingThroughResults.html

```
$obj = new AmazonProductAPI();

$results = array();

for ($i=1;$i<=10;$i++) {
    $parameters = array("Operation"     => "ItemSearch",
                 "SearchIndex"   => "Electronics",
                 "ResponseGroup" => "Images,ItemAttributes,EditorialReview,Offers ",  
                 "ItemPage"=>$i,
                 "Keywords" => $search);

    $results[] = $obj->searchProducts($parameters);

}

foreach ($results as $r) {
    //do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use manufacturer parameter along with BrowseNode to retrieve more than 100 products in a specific category.